# Help me to use DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following three coupled ODEs with six boundary conditions:

```
deq = {pr[x] + a y'[x] + b pr'[x] - c pr''[x] == 0, 
e pt[x] + e2 pr'[x] + l pt'[x] + b2 pr[x]/x - dd pt''[x] == 0, 
v0 pr'[x] + v0 pr[x]/x - dd y'[x]/x - dd y''[x] == 0, y[L] == y0, 
pt[L] == pt0, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == v0 pr[L]/dd, 
pr'[L] == (pr[L] + v0 y[L])/(2 dd), 
pt'[L] == v0 (b2 pr[L] + e pt[L])/(2 dd)} /. 
Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0}, ConstantArray[1, 12]]];

DSolve[deq, {pr, pt, y}, x]
```

but there is no meaningful output. Could anyone help me to solve the equations? What is wrong in my code?

I don't get solutions to the equations even when I put constants equal to 1:

```
L = 5;
deq = {pr[x] +  y'[x] + pr'[x] -  pr''[x] == 0, 
pt[x] + pr'[x] + l pt'[x] + pr[x]/x - pt''[x] == 0, 
pr'[x] + pr[x]/x - y'[x]/x - y''[x] == 0, y[L] == y0, 
pt[L] == pt0, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == pr[L], 
pr'[L] == (pr[L] + y[L]), pt'[L] == pr[L] + pt[L]} /. 
Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0}, ConstantArray[1, 12]]];

DSolve[deq, {pr, pt, y}, x]
```

I tried the first answer as below:

```
L = 5;
DI = 1;
f = 1;
g = 1;
ff = 1;
fff = 1;
fo = 1;
gg = 1;
DD = 1;
Y0 = 1;
pt0 = Cos[Pi/6];
pr0 = Sin[Pi/6];
deq = {pr[x] + g y'[x] + gg pr'[x] - DD pr''[x] == 0, 
pt[x] + f pr'[x] + ff pt'[x] + fff pr[x]/x - fo pt''[x] == 0, 
v0 pr'[x] + v0 pr[x]/x - DI y'[x]/x - DI y''[x] == 0, y[L] == Y0, 
pt[L] == pt0, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == v0 pr[L]/DI, 
pr'[L] == (pr[L] + y[L]), pt'[L] == pr[L] + pt[L]} /. 
Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0, y0}, 
 ConstantArray[1, 13]]];

sol = NDSolve[deq, {pr, pt, y}, {x, 10^-6, 4}];

Plot[Evaluate[{pr[x], pt[x], y[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"pr[x]", "pt[x]", "y[x]"}, {.75, .3}]]
```

but the output graph shows that pt and pr are not equal to boundary condition at x=l.

Comment: If a symbolic solver returns unevaluated, then Mathematica can't solve the problem.  I believe anyone asking for help with such a case should demonstrate that it is reasonable to expect that the problem has a closed form solution.  Mathematica is not a magic box that'll spit out a solution to *any* problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs So true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by **Maple 2017.3** (**By magic box**)

I chose these to solve:

```
deq = {pr[x] + a y'[x] + b pr'[x] - c pr''[x] == 0, 
e pt[x] + e2 pr'[x] + l pt'[x] + b2 pr[x]/x - dd pt''[x] == 0, 
v0 pr'[x] + v0 pr[x]/x - dd y'[x]/x - dd y''[x] == 0, y[L] == y0, 
pt[L] == pt0, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == v0 pr[L]/dd, 
pr'[L] == (pr[L] + v0 y[L])/(2 dd), 
pt'[L] == v0 (b2 pr[L] + e pt[L])/(2 dd)} /. 
Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0}, ConstantArray[1,12]]];
```

[image]

Translated from Maple to MMA:

```
  {pr[x] = (-(1/6))*E^(1 - x)*(-3 + y0) + (1/6)*E^(-2 + 2*x)*(3 + y0), 
  pt[x] = -((E^(-(5/2) - Sqrt[5]/2 + (1/2)*(1 + Sqrt[5])*x)*(-5*E^2 - 
  5*Sqrt[5]*E^2))/(10*Sqrt[5])) + 
  (E^(-(5/2) + Sqrt[5]/2 - (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])*x)*(-5*E^2 + 
  5*Sqrt[5]*E^2))/(10*Sqrt[5]) + 
  (E^(Sqrt[5]*x - (1/2)*(-1 + Sqrt[5])*x)*Integrate[(-(1/6))*E*(-3 + y0)*(-
  E^(-((3*z1)/2) - (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2) + E^(-((3*z1)/2) - (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2)/z1) + 
  ((3 + y0)*(2*E^((3*z1)/2 - (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2) + E^((3*z1)/2 - 
  (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2)/z1))/(6*E^2), {z1, 1, x}])/Sqrt[5] - 
  Integrate[(-(1/6))*E*(-3 + y0)*(-E^(-((3*z1)/2) + (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2) + E^(-
  ((3*z1)/2) + (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2)/z1) + 
  ((3 + y0)*(2*E^((3*z1)/2 + (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2) + E^((3*z1)/2 + 
  (Sqrt[5]*z1)/2)/z1))/(6*E^2), {z1, 1, x}]/(E^((1/2)*(-1 + 
  Sqrt[5])*x)*Sqrt[5]), 
  y[x] == y0 + Integrate[-(((1/6)*E^(1 - z1)*(-3 + y0)*z1 - (1/6)*E^(-2 + 
  2*z1)*(3 + y0)*z1)/z1), {z1, 1, x}]}
```

And Integrated for `x>1`:

```
 solA = {pr[x] = -(1/6) E^(1 - x) (-3 + y0) + 1/6 E^(-2 + 2 x) (3 + y0), 
 pt[x] = -((
 E^(-(5/2) - Sqrt[5]/2 + 
 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) x) (-5 E^2 - 5 Sqrt[5] E^2))/(10 Sqrt[5])) + (
 E^(-(5/2) + Sqrt[5]/2 - 
 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) x) (-5 E^2 + 5 Sqrt[5] E^2))/(10 Sqrt[5]) + (
 1/(6 Sqrt[5]))
 E^(-2 + Sqrt[5] x - 
 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) x) ((
 2 E^(3 - 
 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5]) x) (-1 + E^(
 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5]) (-1 + x))) (-3 + y0))/(3 + Sqrt[5]) - (
 4 E^(-(Sqrt[5]/
 2)) (-E^(3/2) + E^(1/2 (Sqrt[5] - (-3 + Sqrt[5]) x))) (3 + 
 y0))/(-3 + Sqrt[
 5]) + (3 + y0) (-ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5])] + 
 ExpIntegralEi[-(1/2) (-3 + Sqrt[5]) x]) + 
 E^3 (-3 + y0) (ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (-3 - Sqrt[5])] - 
 ExpIntegralEi[-(1/2) (3 + Sqrt[5]) x])) - 
 1/(6 Sqrt[5])
 E^(-2 - 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) x) ((
 2 E^(3/2) (-E^((Sqrt[5]/2)) + E^(
 1/2 (3 + (-3 + Sqrt[5]) x))) (-3 + y0))/(-3 + Sqrt[5]) + (
 4 (-E^(1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5])) + E^(1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5]) x)) (3 + y0))/(
 3 + Sqrt[5]) + 
 E^3 (-3 + y0) (ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[5])] - 
 ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[5]) x]) + (3 + 
 y0) (-ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5])] + 
 ExpIntegralEi[1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5]) x])), 
 y[x] = y0 + 
 1/12 (3 + 2 E^(1 - x) (-3 + y0) - 3 y0 + E^(-2 + 2 x) (3 + y0))}
```

Numerical check:

```
(* for analitic solution: *)

  y0 = 1;
  solA /. x -> 4 // N
  (* {268.969, 503.393, 135.46} *)

(* for numeric solution:*)

  L = 1;
  sol = NDSolve[deq, {pr, pt, y}, {x, 1, 4}];
  {pr[x], pt[x], y[x]} /. sol /. x -> 4 // N
  (*{{268.969, 503.393, 135.46}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer :). Do you think below equation can also be solved by the same method?

Comment: EQ = {y[x] + x y'[x] == 
   v0 pr[x]/Dd + x v0 pr'[x]/Dd, (4 v0 pr0 x + Dd) pr[x] + 
    v0 x^2 y[x]/2 + (2 v0 x^2 pr0 - Dd x) pr'[x] - x^2 Dd pr''[x] == 
   0, y[L] == 1, pr[L] == pr0, y'[L] == v0 pr[L]/Dd, 
  pr'[L] == v0 (pr0 pr[L] + y[L]/2)/Dd}

Comment: Something seems to be wrong… just try `solrule = Unevaluated@(*The last code block*)/. HoldPattern@(a_[x] = b_) :> (a -> Function @@ {x, b});
Simplify[deq /. solrule, x > 1]` The 1st equation isn't satisfied.

Comment: @WatWatson.Maple says an Error:`Error, (in dsolve) found differentiated functions with same name but depending on different arguments in the given DE system: {pr(L), pr(x), y(L), y(x)}
`

Comment: @xzczd.I edited my answer. Maple's `simplify command` something does not work properly or converting from `MathML` is weird.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
L = 5;
deq = {pr[x] + y'[x] + pr'[x] - pr''[x] == 0, 
    pt[x] + pr'[x] + l pt'[x] + pr[x]/x - pt''[x] == 0, 
    pr'[x] + pr[x]/x - y'[x]/x - y''[x] == 0, y[L] == y0, pt[L] == pt0, 
    pr[L] == pr0 , y'[L] == pr[L], pr'[L] == (pr[L] + y[L]), 
    pt'[L] == pr[L] + pt[L] } /. 
   Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0, y0}, 
     ConstantArray[1, 13]]];

sol = NDSolve[deq, {pr, pt, y}, {x, 10^-6, 4}];

LogPlot[Evaluate[{pr[x], pt[x], y[x]} /. sol], {x, 10^-6, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"pr[x]", "pt[x]", "y[x]"}, {.75, .3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I prefer to solve them without ndsolve to understand the effect of each parameter. Do you think it could be possible to do that or not?

Comment: Actually, I need to find a functionality for the solutions.

Comment: Since `DSolve` cannot solve the system with numeric values for all parameters, it is extremely unlikely that  a solution can be found for symbolic parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "numeric values for all parameters"? Can DSolve find the functionality if I determine some parameters and not all of them?

Comment: The `Thread[Rule[{a, b, c, e, e2, l, b2, dd, L, pt0, pr0, v0, y0}, 
     ConstantArray[1, 13]]` sets all of the parameters to `1`, i.e., assigns "numeric values for all parameters". Even with these assignments, `DSolve` cannot solve the simplified system. Complicating the problem by leaving any of the parameters as symbolic is not going to help `DSolve`.

Comment: It seems that NDSolve doesn't pay attention to the boundary condition. Please chek theedit to the question

Answer (score 1):

If you try to find the general solution of your equations without any boundary conditions

```
DSolve[{pr[x] + Derivative[1][pr][x] +Derivative[1][y][x] - (pr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
pr[x]/x + pt[x] + Derivative[1][pr][x] +Derivative[1][pt][x] - (pt^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0,
pr[x]/x + Derivative[1][pr][x] - Derivative[1][y][x]/x - (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0 }
, {pr, pt, y}, x]

(*DSolve[{pr[x] + Derivative[1][pr][x] +Derivative[1][y][x] - (pr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
pr[x]/x + pt[x] + Derivative[1][pr][x] +Derivative[1][pt][x] - (pt^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
pr[x]/x + Derivative[1][pr][x] - Derivative[1][y][x]/x - (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0}, {pr, pt, y}, x]*)
```

MMA can't solve it! So any further activity using DSolve for the complete system seems to be useless!!!

Let's try some simplication:
The first and the last ode only depends on `y[x] , pr[x]` and can be separated:

```
Derivative[1][y][x] = -pr[x] -Derivative[1][pr][x] + (pr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] (* first ode *)
```

substituting in the third ode

```
oder=2 pr[x] + (1 + 2 x) Derivative[1][pr][x] - (pr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] +x(pr^\Prime]\[Prime])[x] - x\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(pr\),TagBox[RowBox[{"(","3", ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x]
```

gives ode in pr which can be solved

```
ergpr = DSolve[oder == 0, pr, x][[1]]
(* {pr -> Function[{x},E^-x C[1] + E^(2 x) C[2] +3 E^-x C[3] (1/3 E^(3 x) ExpIntegralEi[-2 x] - ExpIntegralEi[x]/3)]} *)
```

With this result `y'[x]`is known and y[x] can be evaluated

```
ergy= DSolve[y'[x] == -pr[x] -Derivative[1][pr][x] + (pr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] /.ergpr, y,x][[1]]
(*{y -> Function[{x}, -E^-x C[1] + 1/2 E^(2 x) C[2] + C[4] + 
1/2 E^(2 x) C[3] ExpIntegralEi[-2 x] + 
E^-x C[3] ExpIntegralEi[x] - 1/2 C[3] Log[-2 x] + 2 C[3] Log[x]]}*)
```

Unfortunately the remaining second ode

```
odept = -E^-x C[1] + 2 E^(2 x) C[2] +3 E^(2 x) C[3] ExpIntegralEi[-2 x] +(E^-x C[1] + E^(2 x) C[2] +3 E^-x C[3] (1/3 E^(3 x) ExpIntegralEi[-2 x] -ExpIntegralEi[x]/3))/x -3 E^-x C[3] (1/3 E^(3 x) ExpIntegralEi[-2 x] -ExpIntegralEi[x]/3) +pt[x] + Derivative[1][pt][x] - (pt^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0
```

can not be solved analytically by MMA!

Adaption of the boundary condition y, pr perhaps simplifies the last equation...